# How to show country flag as dropdown in angaularjs and to use it as localization?

Tags: angularjs

I want to use the county flag as dropdown in angular js ?

I found something in GitHub https://github.com/asafdav/ng-flags but that example is not working.

I wanted to use the same for localization.

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1):

well that is just a directiv that renders

```
<flag country="us" size="16"></flag>
```

to:

```
<span class="f16"><span class="flag us"></span></span>
```

it wont localize anything by itself.

there is a lot more work to do. i suggest reading these [article](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n)

look at [i18next](http://i18next.com/pages/doc_init.html)

you should also read [this tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/), the [directive docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) and [$compile docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile) too.

a lot to read, i know, but explaining it all here would take MUCH of time.

i hope i could help, good look and have fun!